# how to assign Amazon S3 objects permissions to a particular IAM group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

How to allow read/write/delete etc, permissions to users in a particular IAM group for a specific Amazon S3 object/file.

Comment: You can attach appropriate IAM policies to the IAM group. Is this not working for you?

Comment: Did you check this AWS document: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: @krishna_mee2004  not talking about buckets, but talking about individual files in the bucket.

Comment: @jarmod and then how to assign that group to that file, and what policy can be added to the group?

Comment: The policy will be similar. Check this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1. In the first link, append your key to the S3 bucket name.

Comment: You don't assign an IAM group to an S3 object. You attach IAM policies to an IAM group (or directly to an IAM user or IAM role). Each IAM policy indicates which resources and which actions are permitted. You can create and attach a policy that specifically allows s3:Get* on resource arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder/cat.png, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work out for me to have have IAM policy with 1 million file details, instead I wanted to have the file have details about the 10-20 groups allowed access on the same, also issues like the file cat.png can be renamed to pets.png in future by the author are there, which would require to modify the IAM policy on the fly with again calculations of millions files.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to control access to "millions" of individual files where access is not based upon the path (directory/folder) of the files, then you will need to **create your own authentication method**.

This can be done by using an [Amazon S3 Pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). Basically:

- Users access your application
- When they request access to a secure file (or, for example, when the application generates an HTML page that includes a link to such a file, or even a reference in an Image tag), the application **generates a time-limited pre-signed URL**
- Users can use this link/URL to access the object in Amazon S3
- After the expiry period, the URL no longer works

This gives your application full control over whether a user can access an object.

The only alternative if you were to use **IAM** would be to grant access based upon the path of the object. It is not a good method to assign access to individual objects.

Comment: Is there a way to map attribute to a file, that these files belongs to these groups in S3, or a separate database mapping is required where we can specify the files and there associated groups. Also does each file has a unique ID in S3?

Comment: Each file has a unique attribute -- it is the **Key** of the file (effectively, it's filename with full path). There is no concept of permission _groups_ for objects in Amazon S3. There are only: very simple permissions on the object level; high-level Bucket Policies; permissions on individual IAM Users/Groups; Pre-signed URLs.